# sum for two power of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, binomial-coefficients, exponential-function, exponential-sum

How do you find the sum for this term 
$$ \cos^{n}(\pi x) + \cos^{n}(\pi y) $$

if  $x-y=a$, where $a\in N^{+}$ and $x,y \in R$

Note: for $n=1$ 
$$ \cos(\pi x) + \cos(\pi y)=0 $$
by use property
$$ \cos(\alpha) + \cos(\beta)= 2\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}) $$

Comment: Hint: what do you know about $\cos(n\pi+\theta)$ and its relation to $\cos \theta$?

Comment: We know that the difference of $x$ and $y$ is a natural number, but are $x$ and $y$ also both natural numbers?

Comment: not necessary, $x, y \in R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \cos^{n}(\pi x) + \cos^{n}(\pi y) $$
$$=\cos^n(\pi y + \pi a)+\cos^n(\pi y)$$

Notice that $$\cos(\theta+ \pi)=-\cos(\theta)$$ and $$\cos(\theta+2\pi)=\cos(\theta)$$

Thus if $a$ and $n$ are both odd integers, the result is $0$; otherwise, the result is $2\cos^n(\pi y)$

Comment: many thanks, if n odd and a belong to R

Comment: @work What do you mean by a belong to R?

Comment: i mean $ a \in N^{+}$

Comment: @work yea, $a$ is an integer. But if $a$ is even, you will get $2\cos^n(\pi y)$; thus the condition for you to get $0$ is when both $a$ and $n$ are odd.

Comment: if  $ a \in N^{+}$ and $n$ is an odd or even

Comment: @work I suggest you pick any even number of $a$, and you'll clearly see that the result is not $0$ :)

Comment: many thanks, your answer is  useful .

Comment: @work You are welcome, glad that you figured it out :)